# Iterate over available classes in a Swift extension?

Tags: ios, swift, class, swift4, extension-methods

Something I have never tried to do before, but I have an extension as seen below (cut for brevity), and I would like to be able to draw out each available color in code. I have never tried this before and cannot bring together the right search words to even get close. Thoughts, pointers?

I would like to get `let availableColors: [UIColor] = magicalFunctionHere(pointing` to extension somehow) ....

I am thinking I will have to create my own function and manually ram in the UIColors found within the extension. I would prefer to automate this though.

```
extension UIColor {
    class func firstColor ( alpha: CGFloat = 1.0 ) -> UIColor {
        return  UIColor.init ( red: 139.0/255.0, green: 322.0/255.0, blue: 405.0/255.0, alpha: alpha )
    }

    class func secondColor ( alpha: CGFloat = 1.0 ) -> UIColor {
        return  UIColor.init ( red: 225.0/255.0, green: 139.0/255.0, blue: 127.0/255.0, alpha: alpha )
    }
}
```

Comment: This might be helpful, and i did see this already, but it is *instance*-based, which is not what i seek. I seek, for example, to be able to query the available colours to create an array from, to then feed a picker. I will re-exmine your link just in case i missed the point ;) .. but, the internal code clearly exists, since it shows up in autocompletions.

Comment: You could use Obj-C runtime or reflection using `Mirror` but in general principles this would be a violation of OOP.

Comment: by the way, instead of having functions with `alpha` parameter, you should prefer having a `let` constant for the color and then just use `UIColor.withAlphaComponent`.

Comment: and second by the way, your color components make no sense. `322.0 / 255.0` is invalid because `1.0` is the max value for the component.

Comment: Thanks sultham.. good catch re the numbers, I simply edited a few from the original git to not just copy somebody else's work. This is git from GitHub that is potentially very helpful in allowing the end user to select colours, but the sheer size of the offerings preclude my doing it manually. I was only doing a poor man's obfuscation ;) (and the alpha issue is part of the git, not my design). For those that are interested, the original is at https://github.com/NorthernRealities/Rainbow. I am evaluating EVReflection to accomplish what i seek.

Comment: I'd tend to recommend SwiftGen to create everything from data at compile-time rather than use reflection techniques (which are fragile, especially in Swift, and subject to interference from other extensions). SwiftGen would dramatically reduce your code duplication and be much more flexible. (Note that SwiftGen writes Swift code, so you can generate the resulting files and check them in, so consumers of your library don't need SwiftGen if you don't want that.) It even has special handling specifically for colors: https://github.com/SwiftGen/SwiftGen#colors

Answer (score 2):

Here is the code using Obj-C runtime methods (notice the @objc prefixes, they are required to make runtime "see" your methods):

```
import Foundation
import XCPlayground
import UIKit

extension UIColor {
    @objc class func fancyColorFirst ( alpha: CGFloat = 1.0 ) -> UIColor {
        return UIColor.red.withAlphaComponent(alpha)
    }

    @objc class func fancyColorSecond ( alpha: CGFloat = 1.0 ) -> UIColor {
        return UIColor.blue.withAlphaComponent(alpha)
    }
}

func methods(in c: AnyClass, where condition: (String) -> Bool ) -> [String] {
    var count: UInt32 = 0
    guard let foundMethods = class_copyMethodList(object_getClass(c), &count) else { return [] }

    let totalMethods = Int(count)
    var matches = [String]()

    for index in 0..<totalMethods {
        let method: Method = foundMethods[index]
        let selector: Selector = method_getName(method)
        let methodName = String(_sel:selector)
        if condition(methodName) {
            matches.append(methodName)
        }
    }
    return matches
}

print(methods(in: UIColor.self, where: { $0.hasPrefix("fancyColor")}))
```

Comment: But a better idea would be to use protocols to declare some kind of "contract" and just check that your class/struct supports it.

Comment: Thank you @Sergiy! i will test this code out and return with the results and check your reply accordingly, cheers! drew..